# redirect emulator port (socket programming)

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image]I know that my question is Repetitive , but My problem does not solved . i'm working on android chat app(socket programming) and I try to test it on emulator , so I need to redirect port of emulator . I search so much but i was not success on redirecting port . is there any one to help me step by step? in fact my problem is that i cant use `telnet localhost 5554` .

Comment: it was my problem and Neiti01 understand it and gave me answer . now i could not understand your problems .

Comment: Development tool questions are specifically on topic.  Closing as a duplicate might be legitimate, but closing as "off-topic" **is not**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use adb to forward ports: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#forwardports

This allows you to forward a local TCP port to a TCP port on the device. You can then telnet into that port

Comment: as i said i read most of this tutorials but in fact my problem is that when i try "telnet localhost 5554" i face with the error that i add to my question .

Comment: You don't seem to have telnet installed. It's not enabled by default on Windows 7 anymore. Check out this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/910.how-to-enable-telnet-client-in-windows-7.aspx or use a third party client like PuTTY: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: tank's a lot , i was forgoten to be consider about it !!